# Outlier Treatment for dataset with multiple columns and datatypes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataset Im working on with close to 30k rows and 180+ columns. Im stuck at the outlier treatment step. I'm using a function(mentioned below) However, im unable to understand the error :

> (""name 'is_numeric_dtype' is not defined"")

Is there any other better method which can be used on large datasets as handling outliers individually is not advisable.

```
def remove_outlier(df):
    low = .05
    high = .95
    quant_df = df.quantile([low, high])
    for name in list(df.columns):
        if is_numeric_dtype(df.name):
            df = df[(df[name] > quant_df.loc[low, name]) 
               & (df[name] < quant_df.loc[high, name])]
    return df
remove_outlier(data_hvc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this snippet, I don't see that you defined the variable is_numeric_dtype. Is that a global variable of some sorts?

Comment: should i specifically define it as a numeric datatype ?

Comment: yes, from what I see you haven't defined it as anything, so you need to define it somewhat like `is_numeric_dtype = (whatever you want it to be)`